# How to manage a json body input with multiple id in Symfony using a DTO

Tags: php, symfony

I have to handle a Json body

```
{
    "idBook": "34567890"
    "idReaders": ["3456789","3456789"]
}
```

with idReader as a list of user who have read the book.
I use a DTO to handle the json but I don't know how to link the id with the object to verify if the two id was good (book object and user object).

```
<?php

class addBookReaderDTO
{
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\NotNull]
    public string $idBook;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\NotNull]
    #[Assert\E]
    public array $idReaders;
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean, to be honest. And have you tried anything? Please explain more clearly what you want to achieve, and what output you want from your code in different cases.

Comment: To make it clear I just want to check in input request if an ID provided in json is a valid id from an entity.

Comment: And to add that I have two id from different entity.

Comment: Ok but  you're just basically repeating what you said in the question, except with less detail, so it doesn't really clarify anything - sorry. Please try again. A couple of things though: 1) once you've got the DTO, then JSON is no longer involved. Per your example, you should end up with a simple PHP object containing a string and an array. So your question is not really about JSON at all. 2) We don't know how you define "valid" in the context of your application. So how can we tell you the way to check if an ID is "valid"? We don't know what test you want to perform.

Comment: "stuff" don't magically happen in Symfony if you use the raw data. Either you have to build some validation yourself, which you can do with custom validators or callback validators in your DTO's (check if a list of users is valid, and return an error or strip invalid data, based on what your api needs to do). 

The second thing I can advise you to look into are [DataTransformers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html). The documentation is related to forms, but the concept used there is the same for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for both of you, I added, like you said, a callback validators in my DTO I also tried to see the dataTransformers and it was useful to help me too.